# Use voltage of canbus wire to control relay

Tags: relay, can

We want to energize a relay when there is data on the canbus wire. When there is no data, the voltage of the line is 0, and when there is data, the voltage is more than 2V. The following diagram should work to energize the relay, but we are afraid that the circuit will affect the data communication, since it's connected to one of the two wire canbus system. Please advise if there is a good way to achieve this without affecting the data communication.

[image]

Comment: "When there is no data, the voltage of the line is 0, and when there is data, the voltage is more than 2V" That's not a CAN bus line (CANH/CANL). So what exactly do you mean with "CAN bus line"? Because the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, the question is how/if you want to separate data and error frames. Someone with the same problem (but LED instead of relay) posted here: https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/290414. Please see my answer there, in particular the **"You'd be creating some manner of crude bus load indicator"** part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the presence of data on a CAN bus without compromising the data on the bus, you are going to need a circuit that has a high input impedance and can detect AC (data changing on the bus - 1's and 0's changing).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT9J6J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first comparator acts as a buffer to the CAN bus. 2.7V was chosen to give 200mV of headroom to prevent false triggering from noise while idle. C2, D1, and D2 act as an AC to DC convertor. D2 and C3 act as an AC filter and peak detector from the previous stage. R4 sets the rate C3 discharges when data isn't changing (the bus is idle). This voltage is compared against the reference voltage (2.7V) and provides and output while data is changing (broadcasting) on the CAN bus. Without doing the math, the output should be high on the order of 10ms from the last recessive to dominant transition. YMMV.

Notes:
You may have to tailor C3 and R4 to optimize your timing requirements. You might also want to add a low ohm resistor (10-100) in series with the output of Comp_1 to limit inrush (outrush?) current of Comp_1. To sample CAN_L instead of CAN_H, a few components can be flipped around. The inputs of Comp_2 can be flipped to change the output polarity.

In practice, you will also want to put a TVS across the comparator input, de-couple the IC, and possibly put a cap across the reference voltage. These parts were omitted for clarity. If using open-collector output comps, pullups will be required.

Comment: This feels needlessly complicated. You could just hook up a monostable multivibrator with Schmitt trigger input and have that one drive the relay - done.

Comment: @Lundin Many solutions exist for this problem. This just happens to be what I wacked up in 5 minutes while answering the question. Is it optimized? No. Does it have lowest part count/BOM? Probably not. Does it work? It should. If your approach is appreciably less complicated, please upload a solution. I'm interested even if WX369 isn't anymore. I feel like your solution will be of similar complexity and part count as mine. Do you accept the challenge?

Comment: My solution is all about chasing down the appropriate IC (retriggerable) and check how you configure the timer for it. But before running off into the woods looking for a solution, we should as engineers question if the problem makes sense to begin with. See my notes to the OP below the question... what they are trying to make might not make any sense at all in the first place. Does it make sense to trigger a relay when there are error frames on the bus, for example? Probably not?

Comment: @Lundin Agreed. But I could only provide solutions with the existing information provided.  If managing error frames is required then the only realistic solution is "listening CAN node microcontroller" solution that can the logic programmed in firmware to decode CAN data and control the relay. Which is probably the best all around solution under any use case cause then you can modify the behavior in FW instead of modifying dedicated circuitry.

Comment: But still, I'm using an 8-pin dual opamp and a few passives as my "retriggerable one-shot". Sure, there's some 6-pin SOT's that LT (Analog) makes et. al., but they still need passives for setting the timing and scaling the input voltage anyway. But I conveniently used whatever parts the CAD tool has available on this site. Also, most engineers have opamps lying around to breadboard this in 30 mins. No special chips required.